# Retraction onto subgroup?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, retraction

Let $N\subset G$ be a nontrivial subgroup of finite group $G$ , is there a "retraction" onto $N$ , i.e. a homomorphism $\varphi : G \rightarrow N$ s.t. $ Im(\varphi) = N $ , $\varphi |_N = id_N $ . Its obviously yes when $N = G$ or $ N = \{e\}$ , if no other cases possible (I could not find them) how to proof ? What about infinite groups ? Is statement true for abelian groups ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidirect_product#Inner_semidirect_product_definitions (your $N$ corresponds with the $H$ in the article, the final bullet point in the linked section is more or less exactly what you say here). They have an "Examples" section you can look at.

Answer (score 3):

Isn't this equivalent to $N$ having a normal complement $K$ in $G$, which would be the kernel of $\phi$?

The case in which $N$ is a Sylow subgroup of a finite group $G$ is studied in transfer theory. For example, Burnside's Transfer Theorem states that if $N \in {\rm Syl}_p(G)$ and $N \le Z(N_G(N))$, then $N$ has a normal complement. This occurs for example in dihedral groups of order $2r$ with $r$ odd and $p=2$, or in $A_4$ with $p=3$.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is related to "splitting exact sequence".

There are many examples: let $G = N_1 \times N_2 \times \cdots \times N_k$, $k > 1$ and $N_i \not= \{e\}$. Then there are natural injections $N_i \longrightarrow G$ and natural projections $p_i: G \longrightarrow N_i$.

The following proposition solves part of the problem and is easy to prove.

**Proposition**. Let $G$ be an abelian group and $N$ is a nontrivial subgroup of $G$. There is a retraction onto $N$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $G\cong N \times H$ for some subgroup $H$.

Comment: They look like examples rather than counterexamples. The OP is not assuming that $N$ is a normal subgroup.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the statement:

> There is a retraction $\varphi:G\to N$.

If $N$ is proper nontrivial, then $\ker(\varphi)$ is a proper, nontrivial and **normal**. In particular pick any simple group $G$ of nonprime order, and any of its proper nontrivial subgroups (which exist by the fact that $G$ has composite order). It will be a counterexample.

This won't even be true even for abelian groups. Take $G=\mathbb{Z}_{p^n}$ for prime $p$. It is not decomposable as direct product of nontrivial groups. And as we will see soon those conditions are equivalent for abelian groups.

More generally if there is a retraction $\varphi:G\to N$ then we have a short exact sequence

$$1\to \ker(\varphi)\to G\to N\to 1$$

which is right split, and so by [splitting lemma for groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splitting_lemma) our $G$ is a semidirect product of $\ker(\varphi)$ and $N$. Conversely any semidirect product will induce such retraction.

In particular if $N$ is normal (e.g. when $G$ is abelian) then there is a retraction $G\to N$ if and only if $N$ is a direct summand of $G$. Which also means that any group of the form $G=N\times K$ will be a valid example.

Comment: Counterexample to what? There was never any suggestion that the retraction exists for all subgroups.

Comment: @DerekHolt "is there a retraction onto  $N$" is a pretty clear suggestion to me. "Is statement true for abelian groups?" as well. In fact half of the written words suggest that. I really don't understand your comment.

Comment: Yes, but then the OP says that the answer is yes if $N=\{e\}$ or $G$, and "if no other cases possible how to proof?", which suggests that the question is are any other cases possible, to which the answer is of course yes! And it is completely unclear what "statement" refers to, since there are no statements. Oh well never mind!

Comment: @DerekHolt my answer fully answers when that is possible, and gives both examples and counterexamples. You are nitpicking.

Comment: I've slightly modified the answer though. Maybe it will be clear now